# How to remove stopwords from dataframe with tokenized data?

Tags: python, dataframe, nlp, nltk, stop-words

I am trying to remove stopwords from dataframe.
Each row has only one column named text where I stored all the paragraphs of article.

This is the very first method I tried

```
stopwords  = ['cat', 'dog', 'lion', 'fox']
df['text'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: str.split(x))
df['text'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: [item for item in x if item.lower() not in stop_words])

x=0

for i in df['text']:
    df['text'][x] = ' '.join(i)
    x += 1
    
df
```

Strangely, this did not remove all the words in stopwords from `df['text']`.
I couldn't figure out why so I moved on to tokenization. After tokenization, each paragraphs were divided and formed columns.

From this dataframe where some rows have more than 50,000 columns, how can I remove words in stopwords?

Thank you

Comment: Rather than manually splitting, replacing, and joining, why not use the built-in [pandas Series.str.replace()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)? It's hard to give specific help since you haven't provided a sample of your input data, but something like `df['text']=df['text'].str.replace("|".join(stopwords),"")` prior to tokenization perhaps?

Comment: @G.Anderson Thank you. Your code works fine too but is It possible to remove stopwords after tokenization where each word in a row(indicating paragraph) is allocated into each column?

Comment: It would help if you show the code you used to tokenize and a sample of your result data

Comment: For example, sklearn's `countvectorizer` and `tfidfvectorizer` both have `stop_words=` as a kwarg you can pass your list into, and a `vocabulary_` attribute you can use after fitting to see (and drop) which indices pertain to which tokenized word. For nltk vectorizers, there are other options

Answer (score 1):

you can try with the following:

```
import pandas as pd

def remove_stop_words(sentence):
    stop_words  = ['cat', 'dog', 'lion', 'fox']
    word_list=sentence.split()
    clean_sentence=' '.join([w for w in word_list if w.lower() not in stop_words])
    return(clean_sentence)
    

    
data = {'text':['the LION eat the cat','the dog is pretty','this Fox looks like a dog','there is no stop word here']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#remove stopword

df['text'] = df['text'].apply(remove_stop_words)
```

result:

```
                         text
0                 the eat the
1               the is pretty
2           this looks like a
3  there is no stop word here
```

another solution can be with pandas.str.replace, but it can create many spaces consecutives:

```
data = {'text':['the LION eat the cat','the dog is pretty','this Fox looks like a dog','there is no stop word here']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
stop_words  = ['cat', 'dog', 'lion', 'fox']
for stop in stop_words:
    df['text']=df['text'].str.replace(stop,'',case=False)
```

result:

```
                         text
0               the  eat the
1              the  is pretty
2         this  looks like a
3  there is no stop word here
```

UPDATE:
You can use Regex to find all words starting by a stop words:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

def remove_stop_words(sentence):
    stop_words  = ['cat', 'dog', 'lion', 'fox']
    for stop_word in stop_words:

        #if you want to exclude only words with string with stop words + 1 letters => Lions
        stop_words.extend(re.findall(r'\b'+stop_word+'[a-zA-Z]*\w+', sentence.lower()))

        #if you want to exclude only words starting with stop words  => Lions,Lionsss
        regex = r'\b(#\w*[^#\W])\b'.replace('#', stop_word)
        stop_words.extend(re.findall(regex, sentence.lower(), re.I))
    word_list=sentence.split()
    clean_sentence=' '.join([w for w in word_list if w.lower() not in stop_words])
    return(clean_sentence)
    

    
data = {'text':['the LIONsss eat the cats','the dogs is pretty','this Fox looks like a dog','there is no stop word here','lionz is not the plurial of lion']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

#remove stopword

df['text'] = df['text'].apply(remove_stop_words)
print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried your code and it works fine but I have one more request. Because text data I am using is in Korean, it's hard to explain but text needs to be tokenized before removing stopwords. (ex. original data is : 1. Renauds 2. Renaudz and I want to delete any words containing Renaud). So in this case, how can I do it? After tokenization, every words in a `text` column would be allocated into new columns

Comment: Minor nitpick, but you can remove the problem with consecutive spaces by replacing with `""` (empty string) instead of `" "` (space character)